# Change View visibility programmatically or through XML?

Tags: java, design-patterns, android

I have an XML layout used by 2 activities. Within this layout, there's a view that is `visible` for `Activity1` and `gone` for `Activity2`. `Activity1` is used more times compared to `Activity2`. I would like to know which of the following methods is a better practice, if there's a better one.

**Method 1**: The view is `gone` and it's turned `visible` with every instance of the `Activity1`.

XML:

```
<View android:id="@+id/myView" android:visibility="gone" />
```

Java:

```
class Activity1 extends Activity {
    ((View) findViewById(R.id.myView)).setVisibility(0);
}

class Activity2 extends Activity {
}
```

**Method 2**: The view is `visible` and it's turned `gone` only when `Activity2` is being used.

XML:

```
<View android:id="@+id/myView" android:visibility="visible" />
```

Java:

```
class Activity1 extends Activity {
}

class Activity2 extends Activity {
    ((View) findViewById(R.id.myView)).setVisibility(8);
}
```

So, is it better to change the visibility programmatically multiple times or fewer times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [View source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java) setting visibility through xml (line 3450) is cheaper than through `setVisibility` method (line 5511).

So it is better to change visibility programmatically fewer times.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use "magic numbers" in your code, otherwise code is unreadable.
`setVisibility(0)` looks like you are hiding the view, while the truth is opposite.
Always use constants (`View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` in this case).

Comment: Constants are already implemented, I just prefer not to use them. The question was regarding a better methodology, not readability of code.

Comment: this is a codereview site ;). and i can just add that preference to not to use constants is very poor.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @slybloty - agree, you are right.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I understand that you've edited my answer to make it look better. But probably you should not change code snippets in areas you are not too familiar about. On Android notation for constants is all-upper-case. And there is no need for some "ViewVisibility" since needed constants defined within SDK View class, as was shown in my answer initially

Comment: I was wondering why those constants were not Android specific.

Comment: @Alex noted, sorry!